# Sqlite3-ruby Missing. But not really

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, sqlite

So Background details: I'm running Ruby 2.2.0 and Rails 4.1.0 in a Ubuntu 12.04.

When I type in `rails -v` I get the error message:

```
Could not find gem 'sqlite3-ruby (= 1.3.1) ruby' in the gems available on this machine.
Try running `bundle install`.
```

When I type in `bundle install`:

I get:

```
Fetching gem metadata from http://rubygems.org/...........
Fetching version metadata from http://rubygems.org/..
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "bundler":
  In Gemfile:
    rails (= 3.0.1) ruby depends on
      bundler (~> 1.0.0) ruby

  Current Bundler version:
    bundler (1.8.4)

This Gemfile requires a different version of Bundler.
Perhaps you need to update Bundler by running `gem install bundler`?
```

The worst part is that it still shows Rails (3.0.1) which is not the current version of rails on my computer.

I tried to install sqllite3-ruby by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

But I get:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libsqlite3-dev is already the newest version.
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  ruby-builder ruby-blankslate ruby-text-format ruby-activesupport-2.3 rubygems ruby-i18n rake libjs-prototype libmemcache-client-ruby1.8
  ruby-actionmailer-2.3 libmemcache-client-ruby ruby-activerecord-2.3 ruby-rchardet ruby-rack ruby-tmail libjs-scriptaculous libtzinfo-ruby1.8
  ruby-rails-2.3 ruby-activeresource-2.3 libtzinfo-ruby ruby-actionpack-2.3
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 455 not upgraded.
```

**Update:**

[image: This is happening! It says that I already have sqlite3 on my computer. Help]

Comment: Again: Check your Gemfile. Your app is looking for sqlite3-ruby version 1.3.1, but you installed version 1.3.3. The versions of the gems in your Gemfile do not accord to the actually installed gem versions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the rails version in your Gemfile. It seems that your App was built with rails 3.0.1. So `bundle install` wants to install all gem versions which are requested in your Gemfile. As the message in your terminal said, rails 3.0.1 depends on bundler 1.0.0, but you currently bundler 1.8.4 installed.

Yo have two possibilities: Either upgrade your existing app to your intsalled rails version (4.2.0) or downgrade all installed rails-dependent gems to rails 3.0.1.